# Importing Facebook SDK crash android app java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

Just importing Facebook SDK crashes my android app, it was working fine but it start to crash, I comment every section uses facebook SDK it still crash
I use facebook sdk version "4.24.0"

```
07-05 12:50:30.309 10354-10412/andrewhossam.cuju_android E/art: No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId() (tried Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId and Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId__)

                                                                --------- beginning of crash
07-05 12:50:30.310 10354-10412/andrewhossam.cuju_android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                           Process: andrewhossam.cuju_android, PID: 10354
                                                                           java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId() (tried Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId and Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId__)
                                                                               at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.<init>(HttpTracker.java:191)
                                                                               at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.<init>(HttpTracker.java:186)
                                                                               at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker.trackConnection(HttpTracker.java:280)
                                                                               at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpsURLConnection$.<init>(HttpsURLConnection$.java:55)
                                                                               at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLWrapper.wrapURLConnectionHelper(HttpURLWrapper.java:40)
                                                                               at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLWrapper.wrapURLConnection(HttpURLWrapper.java:55)
                                                                               at com.facebook.GraphRequest.createConnection(GraphRequest.java:1410)
                                                                               at com.facebook.GraphRequest.toHttpConnection(GraphRequest.java:1070)
                                                                               at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1158)
                                                                               at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1134)
                                                                               at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1118)
                                                                               at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1093)
                                                                               at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:987)
                                                                               at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.getAppSettingsQueryResponse(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:207)
                                                                               at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.access$100(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:47)
                                                                               at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager$1.run(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:122)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-05 12:50:30.311 1104-1960/? E/ActivityManager: App crashed! Process: andrewhossam.cuju_android
```

Comment: have you added internet permission to manifest???

Comment: Yeah sure I did

Comment: Have you still facing that problem??

Comment: I had to create a new project to move on but I don't know what was the problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 24):

Uncheck "Enable advanced profiling" in Run->Edit Config->profiling tab

Comment: I experienced this issue when force closing my app with a START_STICKY service running in the background. Unchecking this seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

after search for days i found it !

add  this  to your manifest file :

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```