# How to solve "UnsatisfiedLinkError" while using Jsoup in an Android BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, jsoup

### What I'm Doing:

In *my app* (Android with `minSdkVersion 15`), I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to [`Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) (A new application package has been installed on the device). Whenever that happens, the receiver tries to fetch some data from the internet using **Jsoup**.

---

### The Problem:

My code below works correctly as long as *my app* is running in the background when I install another app (say from the Play Store). But if I kill *my app* and then install another app, *my app* crashes showing me the "My app has stopped" dialog (because my receiver crashed) as well as this error:

```
No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId() (tried Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId and Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId__)
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.myorg.myapp, PID: 11796
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId() (tried Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId and Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId__)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId(Native Method)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.<init>(HttpTracker.java:191)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.<init>(HttpTracker.java:186)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker.trackConnection(HttpTracker.java:280)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.<init>(TrackedHttpURLConnection.java:49)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpsURLConnection$.<init>(HttpsURLConnection$.java:50)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLWrapper.wrapURLConnectionHelper(HttpURLWrapper.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLWrapper.wrapURLConnection(HttpURLWrapper.java:55)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.createConnection(HttpConnection.java:889)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:727)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:706)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:299)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:288)
    at com.myorg.myapp.InstallReceiver$PlayStoreFetcher.doInBackground(InstallReceiver.java:76)
    at com.myorg.myapp.InstallReceiver$PlayStoreFetcher.doInBackground(InstallReceiver.java:70)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

---

### My Code:

InstallReceiver.java:

```
public class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)) {
            String data = new FetchData().execute("URL").get();

            // The rest of my code...
        }
    }

    private static class FetchData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {    
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                // This is the cause of the problem
                return Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get().text();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myorg.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activities.PlayStoreActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.InstalledAppsActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.PredefinedFiltersActivity"/>

        // This is linking my InstallReceiver.java
        <receiver android:name=".InstallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'

    // The rest of my dependencies...
}
```

---

### My Attempts:

1. I've surround the **Jsoup** call with a general `catch (Exception e)` statement, and yet the error is still being thrown.
2. I looked this error up and found some answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780017) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924486), but none of them seem to address my problem.
3. I moved the **Jsoup** call into an `IntentService` and started that service from my `InstallReceiver`, but the same error is still being thrown (from the service).
4. Tried getting HTML using `(new URL(url)).openConnection()` and got the same error, but now instead of **Jsoup** it says because of `URLConnection`.
5. Used the `Thread` class instead of `AsyncTask`, but still getting the same error.

My attempts hint that the error is not really related to **Jsoup**, it's related to connecting to the internet from the receiver when the app is not running!

I'm guessing that there's an import issue with this `HttpTracker$Connection.nextId()` that's happening when *my app* isn't running.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: The device is connected while you try to debug? if so your stack trace shows it might be a problem with your android studio network profiler
You should report to https://source.android.com/setup/report-bugs
And upgarde your studio if that does not help try and debug using writing log to file

Comment: @crazyPixel I'm getting the same error even if the device is not connected to Android Studio. I checked the error using the logcat app, it's the same.

Comment: whats your minimum supported SDK level?

Comment: @crazyPixel `minSdkVersion 15`

Comment: please see my answer, do update me if it helps

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: @crazyPixel check my comment on your answer.

Comment: @Ibrahim just updated my question with it.

Comment: Can you try another way to accomplish the task? Try getting HTML content with `HttpClient` and parse the HTML with `Jsoup.parse(html).text()` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503574/how-to-get-html-source-code-from-url-in-android)

Comment: Why don't you use Java's Thread instead of stupid AsyncTask?! AsyncTask is a lot harder to debug.

Comment: @SivakumarS I tried your suggestion and surprisingly.. the same error is still showing up. I used `(new URL(url)).openConnection()`, now it's the same error but not because of Jsoup but because of URLConnection :/

Comment: @MDP I tried your suggestion as well, it shows exactly the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens when your'e trying to read a dll/so file that does not exist.

Since what your'e doing is pretty standard the problem is probably on android studio and not on your code.

To solve it - simply raise the minimum sdk to 20 (or more).
(The advanced network profiler crashes and that is since it's not supported under version 20).

Comment: You're right. Even though the error shows up when the device isn't connected to Android Studio, but it seems to be related to something Android Studio compiles into the app itself.

Comment: The first time I raised the `minSdkVersion` to 21 didn't help. But when I deleted my project and cleaned Android Studio of all its traces, then cloned my project's code and built the app after setting `minSdkVersion` to 21.. then it worked! Thanks :)

Comment: but you shouldn't set your min SDK to 21, for now it should be at most 16, I think the problem is from your gradle files. can you add both project level and module level build.gradle files to your Q?

Comment: @OmarEinea The c++ compiler throws this error when it fails on the linkage of dynamic library code since android studio is eventually just an app it also has some bugs in it, for next time ;)