# Android using volley from service

Tags: android, service, android-volley

I am trying to use a service to get my location updates for my app, which is then sends updates to my server every 20 minutes with the users location. The problem I am having is when I try to use volley from service it crashes my app.

I have registered my service in the manifest and it triggers fine, just crashes when it gets to the sending to server part. How would I fix this?

My volley function:

```
public void updateLocation(final double latitude, final double longitude)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "Updating location: " + latitude +"/"+ longitude);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_FOR_ACCOUNT,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Location Response: " + response);
                }
            }, 
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }
   ) {
        //adding parameters to the request
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("command", "updateLoc");
            params.put("account", userAccount);
            params.put("lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
            params.put("long", String.valueOf(longitude));
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
} // END LOCATION UPDATE
```

My logcat crash error:

```
No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId() (tried Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId and Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId__)
03-19 15:58:20.321 21206-21268/my_app:GPS_Service E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
  Process: my_process:GPS_Service, PID: 21206
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId() (tried Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId and Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId__)
      at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId(Native Method)
      at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.<init>(HttpTracker.java:191)
      at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.<init>(HttpTracker.java:186)
      at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker.trackConnection(HttpTracker.java:280)
      at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.TrackedHttpURLConnection.<init>(TrackedHttpURLConnection.java:49)
      at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLConnection$.<init>(HttpURLConnection$.java:42)
      at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLWrapper.wrapURLConnectionHelper(HttpURLWrapper.java:42)
      at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.httpurl.HttpURLWrapper.wrapURLConnection(HttpURLWrapper.java:55)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.createConnection(HurlStack.java:162)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.openConnection(HurlStack.java:179)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:93)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:131)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
      at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
```

Comment: It seems the problem in the profiler. Try to rebuild project and do not use android profiler in Android Studio

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924486/importing-facebook-sdk-crash-android-app-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror) will help

Comment: @Divers I don't use the profiler (that I am aware, I just use the run button), but even if I generate a signed apk file it does that same crash.

Comment: Did you do what @StefanGolubović advice? Still the same?

Comment: I had to create a new project and copy and paste everything over, not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same error, but once turned off "Enable advanced profiling" it started working again.

This setting is found under Run -> Edit -> Profiling